# Why do I get the errors for installing imposm?

Tags: python, linux, redhat

I am trying to install [imposm](https://imposm.org/docs/imposm/latest/install.html) for Python on Red Hat and I get the following error:

[image]

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download get-pip.py, confirm that the file was saved with a .py extension.
Navigate to the location of the downloaded file in the Terminal or Command Prompt.
Run: python get-pip.py

Comment: I get this: `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /home/site.packages`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to install it with Python 3.x but imposm is for Python 2.x

Comment: Oh my bad then! This error just looks like something a python3 interpreter would through because of the difference in the `print` statement/function. 
If you're sure that you're running pip from p2 then I'd go to fixing the code manually although `print` without parenthesis should work in p2. Try adding parentheses in the `setup.py` and `from __future__ import print_function`.
*Those are the steps I'd take and they might not lead anywhere.